# what is new feature of Excel Online vs excel services?

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2013, office365

What is new feature of Excel online (part of office online server) vs excel services?
I read some article like [excel web apps vs excel services](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Comparing-Excel-Services-and-Excel-Web-App-SharePoint-2013-855ee1a3-9263-425d-bccd-4070d2413aa7) but i cant find some article to compare Excel Online and excel services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel Online is a newer version of Excel web app, but it's not available on premise, only in the cloud. It has limitations compared to desktop Excel, but Excel Online is continually updated with new features, whereas Excel web app on your local server will only get updates if there is a service pack or similar. Excel Online integrates seamlessly with Office 365 and SharePoint online.

Excel Online, for example, supports simultaneous editing by multiple users.

Update: In November 2016, the on-premise version of Excel Services received significant step change in SharePoint Server 2016. Office Online can now run on-premise. Details: https://blogs.office.com/2016/11/21/updates-for-excel-services-and-bi-in-sharepoint-2016-on-premises/

Comment: Its not true. i yesterday use it in my local sharepoint without cloud.

Comment: I updated my answer with more recent release information. At the time of writing, my original answer was correct.